# iPhone's Safari: why geolocation prompt appears twice?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, geolocation, mobile-safari

Consider the following iPhone scenario:

1. Select Settings->General->Reset->Reset Location & Privacy (just to ensure all warnings are cleared as a preparation to this test)
2. Open Safari and point to http://maps.google.com
3. Select OK when ["Safari" would like to use your current location] message appears.
4. Select OK again when ["https://maps.google.com" would like to use your current location] message appears right after.

So far so good. Now scroll up so you can see the URL box of Safari, and select the reload button (the rounded arrow next to the URL). This will resubmit the form and will cause the message on step 4 to appear again! (at least on my iOS 6, iPhone 5 device)

Any idea why message appears again after I already confirmed "https://maps.google.com" to use my current location? Is this a known issue?

I encountered this issue in my iPhone based app using UIWebView so I decided to check the same scenario using the built-in Safari app. I was very surprised to find out that this happens with Safari app as well...

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: Yes, but it's not really a solution but part of the design. When using Safari browser or UIWebView control which sends geolocation via HTML5 javascript controls, the user confirmation is expired after 24 hours by design.
My solution was to disable HTML5 geolocation and get the location via iPhone API. I used javascript methods to inject the location coordinates retrieved using iPhone API into the web page. Not most elegant.. but works perfectly and completely removes the confirmation issue.

Comment: Guys, how to solve this issue in plain HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of 2 different types of geo location firing. First you have the native w3c with the safari request and then the Phonegap call from within the browser. I'm having the same issue. 
My problem is that he geolocation in google maps will only  once after resetting the location and privacy settings. Figured out that google has set some restrictions in the fine print. Exploring some open source mappi g options right now (Openstreetmap) which will accept my google kml files.

Comment: Wait what happens only once? "problem is that he geolocation in google maps will only once after resetting". Also could you link to any info about the Google maps fine print?